# Шифр Плейфера. Как вычислить коэффициент, характеризующий вероятность принадлежности к естественному языку?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Пытаюсь выполнить криптоанализ шифра Плейфера. Шифровать и дешифровать умею (пока тренировался только на латинском алфавите). Нашёл статью на хабре про криптоанализ данного шифра https://habrahabr.ru/post/271257/, и тут же возник первый вопрос (в статье на хабре это первый пункт): как вычислить коэффициент, характеризующий вероятность принадлежности к естественному языку?

Comment: Я бы в качестве оценки использовал что-то связанное с частотой  получения часто используемых сочетаний букв, таких как is, are, me, you и т.д. для английского алфавита. Что имел ввиду автор статьи - не знаю)

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из дальнейшего текста,

> Для расчета коэффициентов, определяющих принадлежность текста к естественному языку лучше всего использовать частоты появления триграмм.

То есть, я бы предложил такой алгоритм.

1. Заводим таблицу триграмм, и вычисляем частоты их на достаточно большом тексте (например, на подойдёт «Война и мир» или что-нибудь Диккенса для английского).
2. Для текста-кандидата вычисляем его частоту триграмм, и проверяем среднеквадратичное отклонение частот его триграмм от образцовых частот. Его и можно считать коэффициентом, чем меньше, тем лучше.
3. Для определения «доверительных интервалов» (то есть, какое отклонение можно считать допустимым для правильно расшифрованного текста) лучше обратиться к находящемуся поблизости математику. Если математика в распоряжении не оказалось, можно просто постараться минимизировать коэффициент отклонения.

---

Автор статьи любезно предоставил свой код на гитхабе. [Глядя в код](https://github.com/NeverWalkAloner/Classical-Cryptanalysis/blob/master/breakciphers.py#L217), мы видим, что он пользовался именно триграммами.

Процесс вычисления качества текста (у автора статьи чем больше, тем лучше) выглядит [так](https://github.com/NeverWalkAloner/Classical-Cryptanalysis/blob/master/breakciphers.py#L78):

```
#count how many trigrams contained in the text
def counttrigrams(text):
    return len(text)-3+1

#count how many time specific trigram occurs in the text
def trigramfrequency(text, trigram):
    return text.count(trigram)/counttrigrams(text)

#compare trigram's statistic for specific text with English trigram's statistic
def trigramfitness(text):
    return sum([trigramfrequency(text, k) for k in ENGLISH_TRIGRAMS.keys()])
```

то есть просто сумма частот триграм, входящих в список.

Перевод на C#:

```
static int numberOfTrigrams(string text) => text.Length - 3 + 1;

static int numberOfOccurrences(string needle, string haystack)
{
    int currpos = 0;
    int foundSoFar = 0;
    while (currpos < haystack.Length)
    {
        var foundPos = haystack.IndexOf(needle, currpos);
        if (foundPos < 0)
            break;
        foundSoFar++;
        currpos = foundPos + 1;
    }
    return foundSoFar;
}

static double trigramFrequency(string text, string trigram) =>
    (double)numberOfOccurrences(trigram, text) / numberOfTrigrams(text);

double trigramFitness(text) =>
    EnglishTrigrams.Keys.Select(k => trigramFrequency(text, k)).Sum();
```

Судя по всему, список `ENGLISH_TRIGRAMS` содержит только *популярные* триграммы, и чем чаще они встречаются в тексте, тем считается лучше.

Comment: образцовые частоты - частоты, полученные в результаты анализа, например, романа "Война и мир"?

Comment: @MartinEden: Ага, они. Частоты из большого образца нужного языка.

Comment: т.е. чтобы посчитать коэффициент, нужно сложить сумму часто встречающихся частот триграмм текста кандидата на основе уже имеющегося списка часто встречаемых триграмм?

Comment: @MartinEden: У автора так, хотя я бы собирал среднеквадратичные отклонения.

Comment: начинаю путаться, итак, пусть у нас есть список часто встречающихся триграмм английского языка, мы подсчитываем, как часто они встречаются в нашем тексте, причём подсчитываем именно частоту тех, которые в списке часто встречаемых, а потом просто их складываем?

Comment: @MartinEden: Вы говорите о варианте из кода автора статьи? Да, именно так он и делает.

Comment: тогда другой вопрос, как определить величину, которая нам "скажет", что данную триграмму в нашем тексте стоит принять за ту, которая в списке часто встречающихся? так сказать границы определения "правильной" триграммы

Comment: @MartinEden: Об этом у автора статьи ничего нет. Например, можно взять _N_ самых частых триграмм из образцового текста. Или как-нибудь ещё. За этим обращайтесь к автору, я бы делал по-другому.

Comment: Вы бы сделали так, как описывали ранее, говоря о "доверительных интервалах"?

Comment: @MartinEden: Ага. Сумма частот вообще имеет мало физического смысла.